I need a VBA script to copy and paste rows in excel with a certain step
I need an Excel macro that will copy every sixth row of a particular worksheet, starting from the seventh row, and paste the values ​​of these rows (without shifting or deleting the copied rows containing the formulas) into every sixth row of the same worksheet, starting from the fifth row (Accordingly, copy the formula values ​​of the seventh line and paste into the fifth, copy 13 and paste into 11, and so on until the last significant line). I don’t understand programming at all, and neither neural networks nor my attempts gave the desired result. I ask you for help, friends.
Sub Copy_And_Insert_Rows()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 6 To lastRow Step 6
        Rows(i).Copy
        Rows(i - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

The neural network produced this result, but it does not do what I need, shifting the rows down.
At the request of the commentator, I am clarifying my requirements for the macro. I made the following code for three lines:
Sub Copy_And_Insert_Rows()
Range("d7:crg7").Copy
Range("d5:crg5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("d13:crg13").Copy
Range("d11:crg11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("d19:crg19").Copy
Range("d17:crg17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub

Essentially I need the same thing, but for several thousand lines, which requires more advanced code.

You'll need to clarify what it is you want. You talk about copying every sixth line and pasting it, but you don't mention where It might be useful for you to show us sample data, the expected result and explain how the code you provided fails to meet it

Do you need to insert new rows, or just copy content into existing rows?

Or copy in a different worksheet or workbook?

I added a new piece of code to make it clearer what I need. Yes, I want to copy data to already existing rows.

Try this code:
Sub Copy_Rows()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To lastRow Step 6
        Rows(i).Columns("B:CRG").Copy
        Rows(i - 2).Columns("B:CRG").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

You may restrict copy/paste to columns you actually need.

Thank you very much, this is what I wanted. Is it possible not to touch the row names (column A) or do I need to look for some workarounds?

I added an update.

Thanks to MGonet's solution, I found a solution for my commentary on his solution. Sorry for my English :)
Sub next_turn_vnutr_rinok()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To lastRow Step 6
    Rows(i).Copy
    Rows(i - 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Cells(i - 3, 1).Copy
    Cells(i - 2, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

